# What/Why does WinRT Create New Clean Layout Randomly

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, build, windows-runtime

So occasionally and seemingly randomly when developing WinRT apps Visual Studio goes through a lengthy process that starts with "Creating a new clean layout..." I would love more information about the build and deployment process involved with WinRT apps. I understand the concept of creating an application that runs in a sort of sandbox environment, but I'm looking for information about that sandbox environment. Also (this may sound silly) but what is different about the executable created that runs in the sandbox and why can't it be run as a standalone? Thanks for the information in advance.

I've tried to do some research about this, but there seems to be limited knowledge about this part of WinRT.

EDIT:

I'm going to start a bounty on this because I really don't understand it and Google/Microsoft are unusually barren when I search for this. So the questions to receive the bounty are:

- What are the details around the build/deployment process of a WinRT/Windows Store app?
- What's actually going on during the "Creating a new clean layout..." stage?
- What is the difference between a traditional executable and a Windows 8 app that runs in a sandbox environment? How are these apps launched/managed?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [Windows Dev Center for Win Store Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/apps/jj679957)? It tells you literally step-by-step what it takes to get it to [market](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/apps/br230836.aspx). You'll need a dev account, the Windows App Certification Kit, and their approval.

The sandbox refers to AppContainers [which were integrity levels in Vista](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/10/better-on-the-inside-under-the-hood-of-windows-8/). The sandbox limits/requires explicit [declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx) for certain privileges.

See [Security in Windows Store apps](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-123) for an idea of how sand boxing/security work.

Windows 8 and RT Windows App Store dev is pretty similar. See this [Windows Store app development for Windows RT PCs Whitepaper](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30703) for some differences.

Hope this gets you started.

EDIT 1:

If you're interested in the MSBuild process, read "Inside the Microsoft® Build Engine: Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build" and the supplement "Supplement to Inside the Microsoft Build Engine: Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build". Unfortunately, I don't remember RT being explicitly mentioned, but windows 8 is pretty close.

See [App packages and deployment (Windows Store apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464929.aspx) for how apps are managed/deployed from the store ([relevant MSDN post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/04/25/deploying-metro-style-apps-to-businesses.aspx)).

See also [Windows Store Apps with HTML5 Refresh: (05) Packaging and Deployment](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/html5refresh/05).

Comment: You get the bounty on this one because I don't want NOBODY to get it. This is some really good info, but when I say build/deployment I mean VS building and deploying, not deploying to the market. That's why I mentioned the step "Creating a new clean layout" which I still don't know what that even means. You provided the most useful information I've seen yet, but if you have **anything** else to share about this I would love to read it. Thanks!! And enjoy the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

I've also hit this issue seemingly out of the blue. I think I have the answer. There's a check box in the project settings Debug **Uninstall and re-install the package....**. See screeshot

[image: VS 2017 Uninstall and reinstall my package... project settings]

Answer (score 0):

Someone needs to ask this question again. This is really messing up my development process because I'm randomly losing all my documents when I deploy and I don't understand why.