# Updating existing UWP package deletes app data of the older app version

Tags: c#, uwp, manifest, appx, appxmanifest

1)I am trying to update my existing UWP app with a new release. I have added this package to the Microsoft store. However when I install the new release all the previous app data get cleared. How can I get the old app data when I install the new release of the app.

2)Also currently my app data is stored in C:\Users(user name)\AppData\Local\Packages(Package Name)\LocalState. I would like the package to be created directly in the Local folder rather than the Packages folder. Can this be done in UWP?

Answer (score 1):

1) Make sure your using the same package name and just increment the version number.
See [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52306056/7446765).

2) I'm pretty certain this isn't possible. What reason do you have for wanting this requirement?

Comment: 2) I'm pretty certain this isn't possible. What reason do you have for wanting this requirement?  With regards to this question. I would like to have the folder structures similar to my other applications or Programs on my system. I would want my UWP app to be present outside the Packages folder, can be in the Roaming Folder where my other applications are stored eg. Skype, Notepad ++ etc C:\Users(user name)\AppData\Roaming

Answer (score 1):

This is a debug only feature, updating the app through the store will persist the local storage and other locations for the end users involved.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I have found the solution. The Package name needs to be the same each time we upload the file.